# SQL Server express maintenance

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-express

I'm currently trying to develop a solution for data logging related to a SCADA application, using SQL Server 2012 Express. The SCADA application is configured to execute a stored procedure on SQL Server to push data in the db.

The data flow imho is quite heavy ( 1.4 - 1.9 m rows per day, averaging 43 bytes in length, after some tweaks). The table which stores data has one clustered index on three columns. For now our focus is to store this data as compactly as possible and without generating too much fragmentation (SELECTS are not of major interest right now).

Currently the DB occupies ~250 MB (I have pre-allocated 5120 MB for the DB), and holds only this data table one other table which can be ignored, and the transaction logs.

My questions are:

1. How can I setup index maintenance on this DB? Being Express edition I can't use SQL Server agent. I'll use task scheduler but should I use rebuild or reorganize? Is it advisable to use a fill factor under 100? Should I configure the task scheduler to call at intervals such that the task will only reorganize (fragmentation under 30%)? Is rebuilding an increasingly expensive operation (day x index is rebuilt, will day x+1 take less time to rebuild as opposed to rebuilding only once in 2 days), after it reaches max storage space?
2. Again having SQL Server Express edition limits the data capacity to 10 GB. I'm trying to squeeze as much as I can in that amount. I'm planning to build a ring buffer - can I setup the DB such that after I get in the event logs the message that the alter database expand etc. failed the stored procedure will use update on oldest values as a means of inserting data (my fear is that even updates will take some new space, and at that point I'll have to somehow aggressively shrink the DB)?
3. I have also considered using a compressed win partition to store the files of the DB, and using a free unlimited DB such as MySQL for storage purposes, and SQL Server only as a frontend - the SCADA app must be configured with SQL Server. Is that worth considering?
4. To optimize inserts I'm using a global temp db which holds up to 1k rows (counting with a sequence) as a form of buffer and then push the data into the main table and truncate the temp table. Is that efficient? Should I consider transactions for efficiency instead - I've tried to begin a named transaction in the stored procedure if it doesn't exist and if the sequence is reaching 1k commit the tran? Does increasing the threshold to 10k rows lead to less fragmentation?

If you're thinking I'm unfamiliar with Databases then you are right. Atm there is only one scada application using SQL Server, but the actual application is setup redundantly so at the end everything will take twice the resources (and each instance of the SCADA application will get its own storage). Also I need to mention that I can't just upgrade to a superior edition of SQL Server, but I have the freedom to use any piece of free software.

Comment: You are asking four questions in one. Please put one question in one post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the answers cross over the 4 numbers, so I just put responses in bullets to help:

- Indexes should probably be maintained, but in your case, they can be prohibitive. Besides the clustered index on the table, indexes generally (the nonclustered type) are for querying the data.

  - To let a Scheduled Task do the work since no Agent can be use, the sqlcmd utility (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The command line tools may have to be installed, but that let's you write a batch script to run the SQL commands.
- With an app doing as much inserting as you describe, I would design a 2-step process. First, a basic table with no nonclustered indexes to accept the inserts. Second, a table you'd be querying the data. Then, use a scheduled task to call a stored proc to transfer transactional data from table 1 to table 2 perhaps hourly or daily based on your query needs (and also remove the original data from table 1 after transfer to table 2 - this should definitely be done in a transaction).

  - Otherwise, every insert has to not only insert the raw data for the table, but also insert the records for the indexes.
  - Due to the quantity of your inserts, high fill factors should probably be avoided (probably set to less than 50%). A high (100%) fill factor means the nonclustered indexes don't leave any space in the pages of the tables to actually insert records. Every record you insert means the pages of the table have to be re-organized. Having a high fill factor will leave space in each page of the table so new records can be inserted in indexes without having to reorganize them.
- To optimize your inserts, I would use the 2-step process above to insert records straight into your first table. If you can have your app use SQL Bulk Copy, I would explore that as well.
- To optimize space, you can explore a few things:

  - Do you need all the records accessible in real time? Perhaps you can work with the business to create a data retention policy in which you keep every record in the database for 24 hours, then a summary by minute or something for 1 week, hourly for 2 weeks, daily for 6 months, etc. You could enhance this with a daily backup so that you could restore any particular day in its entirety if needed.
- Consider changing the database level from full recovery to simple or bulk-logged. This can control your transaction log with the bulk inserts you may be doing.

  - More Info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190692%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
- You'll have to work hard to manage your transaction log. Take frequent checkpoints and transaction log backups.

Comment: While server agent is not working, you can schedule your procedures or any sql command using a batch file and run it from windows task  scheduler.

Comment: Unfortunately using sql bulk copy is, from what I understand, not an option since that's a programmatic approach and the scada app is a closed  system. I can only point to which server to push the data and what db with credentials etc. Is using a global temp db not acceptible (it has no index whatsoever)? My intention is not to argue but to actually learn something.

Comment: The tempdb is fine, but make sure your tempdb is following best practices in its configuration (just google "tempdb best practices"). You'll at minimum want to set a min size at a substantial level so that you aren't constantly auto-growing - anytime your db instance restarts, tempdb resizes to default size). You'll also want to setup at least 4 data files (usually, at least 1 per CPU core) to minimize contention on tempdb resources. There are few other good practices as well you'll find.